# Filter users by unique id and higher score

Tags: sorting, filter, logic, react-tsx

Thank you in advance. First of all, I`ll try to explain my problem. I have a history of users (array) and many days in this history (also arrays) and every day has users (objects) which I take from get query.
It turns out such a structure:  [ [ {} ,{},{},{} ], [ {},{},{} ], [ {},{},{} ] ]. My goal: I want to show unique top users (every user has own unique ID during all history), sorting users by score. I have already have filtering unique (by id) top (by score) users (first image) and I also have sorting users by score (second image)

But I can't combine these two functions into one logic.I'd be very grateful to someone who can solve it

[image: first picture filters unique users]
[image: second picture finds the higher user score from all history]
[image: also my Redux state]